# C# - How To Use ProgessBar While DataGridView Filling

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, progress-bar

I have a DataGridView and it has so many rows. It takes a long time to load. And I want to add a ProgressBar when it load. How can I add a ProgressBar with manquee style to my code. (P.S. : I don't know my DataGridView's rows count, it change everytime.)

It's my code;

```
     conection.Open();
     string[] ss = listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString().Split(' ');
     int countss = ss.Count();
     for (int mi = 0; mi < countss; mi++)
     {
         string mq = "select c1, c2, c3 from myTableName WHERE c1='" + ss[mi] + "' OR c2='" + ss[mi] + "'";
         SqlDataAdapter s = new SqlDataAdapter(mq, connection);
         DataTable d = new DataTable();
         s.Fill(d);
         foreach (DataRow r in d.Rows)
         {
             dgv1.Rows.Add(r["c1"].ToString() + " " + r["c2"].ToString(), r["c3"]);
         }
     }
     //Some insignificant operations...
     for (int mi2 = 0; mi2 < cmn; mi2++)
     {
         string mq2 = "select c1, c2, c3 from myTableName WHERE c1='" + cmn[mi2] + "' OR c2='" + cmn[mi2] + "'";
         SqlDataAdapter s2 = new SqlDataAdapter(mq2, conection);
         DataTable d2 = new DataTable();
         s2.Fill(d2);
         foreach (DataRow r2 in d2.Rows)
         {
             dgv2.Rows.Add(r2["c1"].ToString() + " " + r2["c2"].ToString(), r2["c3"]);
         }
     }
     coneciton.Close();
```

Comment: Create a new form with a progress bar in it. Run the form using form.show(), then update value on progress bar every time you add a row, total row count you can get from d.rows.count, using that you can calculate total completion. If you want to use show dialog however that can be tricky

Comment: @Anil Hi sir. Do you have an example code or an article about how I can do this? I'm a new coder. Sometimes I have trouble understanding. Thank you...

Comment: Is it possible to without foreach?

Comment: Do a google search on `DataGridView.DataSource`.

Comment: In addition, as I previously stated, you should be looking at ways to get the data to load faster. Adding a progress bar is only going take it longer.

Comment: But I have to form it like c1 + " " + c2. Is it possible with this way?

Comment: I am confident you can/should do this “sum” in the sql select query string `mq` … it can do these sums and it may be quicker.

Comment: Good idea. I will try it. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataTable g = new DataTable();
        int rowCount = g.Rows.Count;
        Progress_tracker pForm = new Progress_tracker();
        pForm.Show();
        int rCount =0;
        foreach (DataRow r in g.Rows)
        {
            //do somethin

            pForm.progressBar1.Value = 100*rCount++ / rowCount;
        }
    }
```

this is code example on how to update

```
private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.progressBar1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // progressBar1
        // 
        this.progressBar1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(37, 64);
        this.progressBar1.Name = "progressBar1";
        this.progressBar1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(354, 23);
        this.progressBar1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // Progress_tracker
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(530, 154);
        this.Controls.Add(this.progressBar1);
        this.Name = "Progress_tracker";
        this.Text = "Progress_tracker";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }
```

this is designer code for Progresstracker window which has just one control a progress bar, remember to keep its modifier public so you can access it outside the class, i.e. by main form

Comment: Hi again. How did you generate Progress_tracker?

Comment: Its just a form with a progress bar with public access, Create a form, add progress bar, change modifier to public, to add new form right click on your project name add form

Comment: OK. I will try it.